# Embedding Flash SWF

Tags: html, flash, embed

I am trying to make a mockup of this website for a class project: http://www.smokeybear.com/campfire-safety.asp

I have all the elements loaded just fine, except I can't seem to make it load the flash\clock.swf right above the *Approximate number of acres burned* on the right-hand side.

Since I don't have a copy of the swf saved locally on my hard drive, I was trying to reroute it to the actual url of the swf. What it is currently showing is the grey space for the counter, without the orange numbers. Here is the clip of code from the page source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">getCounterFlash()</script>
            <noscript>
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="190" height="45" id="clock" align="middle">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.smokeybear.com/flash/clock.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />    
            <embed src="http://www.smokeybear.com/flash/clock.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="190" height="45" name="clock" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
            </object>
            </noscript>
```

Here is the getCounterFlash() from the js:

```
function getCounterFlash() {
document.write('<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="190" height="45" id="clock" align="middle"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.smokeybear.com/flash/clock.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><embed src="http://www.smokeybear.com/flash/clock.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="190" height="45" id="clock" name="clock" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" wmode="opaque" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /></object>');
}
```

Haven't really played with embedded flash objects too much, so could anyone advise on what values I should change to get it to work like it is working on the original site? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may not entirely understand your problem. 
Assuming you have tested various browsers. 
Seems to me you are missing a second path. If you go to the originals, and look at this example: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html
there are two movie_name.swf

and you have two close tags for js?

Comment: I edited my original post. Hopefully that clarifies what I am trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I still do not understand, but I would remove all the noscript js, closing tags included, validate the site with w3 validator (you have a bunch of errors), and if still no luck, use Adobes template for embedding swf. And note that the url/path to your swf goes in two places in that bit of code.